# NodeJS and GraphicsMagick: resize() destroys image quality

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-resizing, graphicsmagick

I'm using GraphicsMagick to resize and store images uploaded to my web application.
The problem is that even setting the quality to 100, the quality of the images is destroyed and they look very ugly.

The code I use is like this:

```
// ... "data" is the Buffer object I obtain from the upload
gm(data)
    .quality(100)
    .resize(600)
    .write("/path/to/write", function (err) {
        ...
    };
```

I think I'm doing something wrong, but I can't find where is the mistake.
I've searched the documentation, I've googled, searched through all questions here, but I didn't find anyone having the same problem as mine.

All help will be appreciated, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Big Images equals big problem.

Not only because of the quality you lost but the time the process takes.

I suggest you do it with [thumbnail](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/api/resize.html#thumbnailimage) method or deep into resize specifying arguments using [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) in a way like this:

```
gm.resize({
  srcData : img,
  strip : false,
  width : 173,
  height : "173^",
  customArgs: [ 
    "-gravity", "center"
    ,"-extent", "173x173"
  ]
}).write("/path/to/write", function (err) {
```

...and avoid nesting and concating funcions.

To use imagemagick you can do it this way

```
var imageMagick = gm.subClass({ imageMagick: true });
```

Then use imageMagick the same way you'd normally use gm.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I didn't find these parameters for resize() in the documentation. Do you have a link or something where I can read to go more deep in detail?

Comment: This is because I am using gm with imagemagick, that is a big win

Answer (score 0):

i also had image quality problem with gm and then i have used this module.
https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp it worked for me. I image quality after resizing was much better